# Centos 7 Move storage space from one filesystem to another

Tags: centos, filesystems, xfs

I have a server using Centos 7, and with the storage capacity allocated as such:

[image: My free space and mounts]

What I would like to do is take some of the space from the **/dev/mapper/centos-home** file system and give it to **/dev/mapper/centos-root**.

Now, I am aware I have to unmount the /home and remount it somehow at a smaller size. Then reallocate the free space. But, will this cause issues, as in being able to login and such?

I know you won't be able to unmount /home on el7 without turning off some services, like cups.

Also, if it is a XFS filesystem I know you cannot shrink it. So, how would I go about it for a XFS system?

As per Sven's request the command `blkid /dev/mapper/centos-home` returned nothing.

Comment: You should find out why the root filesystem has gotten full.

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyze, what takes such space using *du* command:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /
```

If you realize that e.g. /var/log/apache is too large, you can stop apache, move /var/log/apache to /home/log/apache and create link:

```
ln -s /home/log/apache /var/log/apache
```

Then you can start apache.

Comment: I ran `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du | sort -n | tail -20 | cut -f2 | xargs -I{} du -sh {}` to see top 20 biggest files and they are all from the /home.

Comment: You should add `-x` to the `du` command.

Comment: Have done. Same result

Comment: Try again _du -h --max-depth=1 /_ to find, which directory is large and ignore /home. If you use find you've mentioned above, you should exclude /home directory using _find . -type f -not -path "/home/*"_.

Comment: @JanPapež-honyczek 40G     /var

Comment: So run _du -h --max-depth=1 /var_

Comment: /var/www is 21gb and /var/lib is 18gb. Also, you stated "You should add -x to the du command" first du or second?

Comment: _-x_ is parameter of _du_ command (du -x). But it is not so important. Now you know, that /var/www has 21GB. In this directory are files for your web server. Go to subfolders to find large files (again with _du_ command and ls -l command). You can delete them if they are not important. If you want them, move directory /var/www to /home/www and create link _ln -s /home/www /var/www_

Answer (score 0):

You said the FS is XFS. In this case, you can't reduce it's size (this is an inherent limitation of XFS).

- **Make and test a backup.** This is important!
- If you can't unmount `/home`, boot into a rescue system, umount it otherwise.
- Delete the logical volume for home
- Create a new one with a smaller size
- Create a new FS on it and mount it.
- Extend the logical volume for `/`.
- Grow the root filesystem, e.g. with `xfs_growfs` (XFS) or `resize2fs` (ext4).

Comment: can I backup to my local computer or say bitbucket ?

Comment: The idea of a backup in this case is that the data is safe in case you do something wrong. Having a backup in your local system will be counterproductive for this use case.

Comment: Sven my root won't be able to possibly have backup saved on there, not enough space

Comment: A backup on the machine is useless anyway, as anything that goes wrong with your machine goes also wrong with the backup. If your data is at all important, you *need* an external backup, not only for this file system modification.

Comment: Indeed. Also, Sven if I bought a new SSD am I able to transfer the data from old smaller drive to the new one?

Comment: Sven's answer assumes you have no additional disks and you need to use backup restore. (You need a backup of anything important anyway.)  Certainly if you had another disk you could move things there. It is possible to `vgextend`, `pvmove`, and `vgsplit`  and end up with multiple VGs.

Comment: @JohnMahowald: I would never do something like this with an "backup" that is mounted live to the system. Too many ways to shoot yourself in the knee when touching partitions, file systems and the like.

Comment: I meant proper offline backup, so that any mistake would not lose data. As of now, the answer destroys the home LV, so that first step of backing it up is important if that data is valuable.

Comment: @Ah, sorry, I didn't get the full intent of your post. You are right of course.

Comment: What would be the best way to create a proper offline backup?